# solve the limit of $(y_{n})$, $y_{n}=1+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have the following sequence $(x_{n})$ , $x_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ which has the limit $\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$.I need to calculate the limit of the sequence $(y_{n})$, $y_{n}=1+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^{2}}$

I don't know how to start.I think I need to solve the limit for the whole sequence ( even n + odd n) then from the "big limit" I should subtract $\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$, right?

Comment: Can you write the terms from the sum you know that are missing from the sum you want and compute that difference?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: I will be more carefull in the future.The terms that are missing are $\frac{1}{2^{2}},\frac{1}{4^{2}},...\frac{1}{(2n)^{2}}$ and if I complete $(y_{n})$ I get $x_{2n}+y_{n}$

Answer (score 5):

Use $$\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
Also, we can write the following.
$$1+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}-\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\right)=$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\rightarrow...$$
I got $\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$

Comment: Thank you for your anwer.It's the right one.It passed almost an hour and I still don't understand the approach.From what you wrote I get $x_{2n}=\frac{1}{4}x_{n}$ and $\frac{1}{1^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^{2}}=x_{2n}+y_{n}$.

Comment: @DaniVaja I added something. See now.

Comment: @DaniVajad $x-\frac14x=? $.

Comment: So I got $y_{n}=x_{2n}+y_{n}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot x_{n}$

Comment: @DaniVaja See my post and just calculate $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$

Comment: So $1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$ tends to $\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}$ too

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!I understood!

Comment: You are welcome!